# Mutt, empty email account from command-line

Tags: command-line-interface, cron, mutt

trying to figure out a cli way to empty all email from a specific email account.

It is certainly possible to type:

```
mutt -f account
D
~s .*
then quit....
```

Is there a way to do this all from cli/cron?

Comment: How is the mail stored?  How are you accessing it?  What type of mail storage is in use (mbox/maildir/other)?

Comment: /var/spool/mail/ :)  Local email accounts.  No need for pop3/imap account stuff right now.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But `echo -n > /var/spool/mail/account` does the trick.

Comment: Make sure to do this as the user in question and not root or the file will end up with the wrong ownership.

Comment: exactly why it would be nicer to bang this out via mutt, no? :) hence the mutt question, not a trick with echo/touch/etc :)

Comment: (+1) So you'd rather have Mutt analyze every mail header and "re-render" an empty mailfile using billions of CPU and Disk cycles?  Do the echo.  It doesn't matter who you do it as if the file already exists the permissions will not be changed.  Also, just for cleanliness lets do `echo -n > /var/spool/mail/account` so it doesn't start with a newline.

Comment: You don't need the echo. `>/var/spool/mail/account` works and leaves a blank file rather than one with a linfeed in it.

Answer (score 2):

Would `rm /var/spool/mail/account` do the trick ?

Comment: dont know... that depends if postfix/dovecot wont complain about its absence, and recreate it!

Comment: That was rhetorical.